# Find the value of a and b, given $51a20b5$ is divisible by $165$.

Tags: number-theory

So to do this problem I tried:

$165=5(33)$

So $5-1+a-2+0-b+5=11m$, hence $7+a-b=11m$

And $5+1+a+2+0+b+5=3n$, hence $13+a+b=3n$

How would I proceed from here to find the values of a and b?

Comment: $-2 \leqslant 7 + a - b \leqslant 16$, so $7 + a - b = 0$ or $7 + a - b = 11$, i.e. $b = a + 7$ or $a = b+4$. Also, $a+b+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standards.

$165$ is divisible by $3$ but not $9$.  That means the sum of the digits of $51a20b5$ are divisible by $3$.

And $165$ is divisible by $11$ so the sum of the even placed digits and the sum of the odd placed digits differ by a multiple of $11$.

$165$ is divisible by $5$ but that only means the last digit is $5$ or $0$ and we already know that.

So $5+1+a+2+0+b+5 = 13 + a+b$ is a multiple of $3$.  So $1+a+b$ is a multiple of $3$.

And $5+a +0+5 = 10+a$ and $1+2+b= 3+b$ and so $(10 +a)-(3+b)= 7+(a-b)$ is a multiple of $11$.

So But $-9 \le a-b < 9$ so $7+(a-b)= 0, 11$ and $a-b=-7$ and $a=b-7$ or $a-b=4$ and $a = b+4$.

Well, try them: $a=b-7$ and $1+a+b=2b-6$ is divisible by $3$. So $b$ is divisible by $3$  So of our options $(a,b)=(0,7),(1,8),(2,9)$ the only possible solutions is if $3|b$ or $a=2$ and $b=9$ is a solution.

$5122095\div 165=31043$.

If $a=b+4$ then $1+a+b=5+2b$ and if $b=0,1,2,3,4,5$ then $5+2b=5,7,9,11,13,15$ and $9$ and $15$ are divisible by $3$ so $b=2,a=6$ and $b= 5,a=9$ are solutions.

$5162025\div 165 =31285$

$5192055\div 165 =31467$

Comment: There is also a solution when a=9, b=5, how would you find that?

Comment: That is not a solution as as $4+a+b= 18$ is divisible by $9$ (notice I had that with $8+2b = 8,10,12,14,16,18$) and $165$ is not..... oh, scrod!  .... what a brain fart!!!  Just because $165$ is not divisible by $9$ doesn't mean $165k$ is not!.... I can't believe I did that!  .... I'll edit to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

$a-b=11m-7$

As $ -9\le a-b\le9,-9\le11m-7\le9\iff-9+7\le11m\le9+7\implies m=0,1$

If $m=0,b=a+7\ge7$ and $a+7\le9\iff a\le2$

$7(7)-7\le2b-7=a+b=2a+7\le2(2)+7$

As $a+b+13=2(a+1)+7+13-2$ must be divisible by $3,$

$3$ must divide $a+1\implies a=2$

What if $m=1?$

Comment: How did you get $7(7)-7\le2b-7=a+b=2a+7\le2(2)+7$?

Comment: @Jamminermit, Observe that $$m=0\implies a\le2,b\ge7$$